# Difference between .NETs using-Statement and Javas try-with-ressources

Tags: java, c#, using-statement, try-with-resources

I learned C# in school and now I started to learn Java.

In Java there is "try with ressources" which will close/dispose stuff (like a Scanner) when it's not used anymore.

The equivalent C# is the using-Statement, which basically does the same.

Are they really *exactly* the same, or are there any differences (like what they are doing in background)?

Comment: Of course there are differences: They're different statements, in different languages, running on different platforms. What *specifically* do you want to know? What's the concrete question here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, they're not *exactly* the same.

- `try-with-resources` statements can declare multiple variables of different types; `using` statements can declare multiple variables, but they all have to be of the same type
- A `using` statement doesn't *have* to declare any variables; `using (foo)` is fine - whereas a try-with-resources statement
- A variable declared in a `using` statement is still assignable, although it's still the initial value which is disposed, rather than the value at the end of the block; a variable declared in a `try-with-resources` statement cannot be assigned within the block
- A `try-with-resources` statement can have `catch` and `finally` blocks, whereas you'd need to have a separate `try`/`catch` or `try`/`catch`/`finally` block in C#
- If the body of a `using` statement throws an exception, and then the `Dispose` method throws an exception, then only the latter exception is available; in `try-with-resources` the exceptions from closing are "suppressed" (so the statement result is the exception from the `try` block) but the closing exceptions can still be retrieved using `Throwable.getSuppressed`.

Comment: Starting from C# 8 there is also `using declaration`, where it doesn't introduce a new scope, but uses enclosing scope, [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using#using-declaration)